charging and discharging capacitors in series with no current circulating
in a circuit with three capacitors in series (or plus) how does the in-between capacitor charge and discharge if there isn't circulating current?

If charge is moving, there is current (by definition), and Kirchoff's Current Law states that the sum of all currents at any node is zero, so that current must be "circulating".

what you mean by charge?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge

i can't imagine a "physical property"  that moves!!!

Water moves. You measure the flow in litres per second for example. Same with current flow, except it’s not volume per second but electron count per second, scaled in Coulombs so that 1C>>1e.

then electrons flow from plate to plate traversing the dielectric barrier !?

The negative and positive charges of the initially "neutral" wire and plates of two capacitors it is connected to, start to being "attracted" to the plates, effectively resulting in current.
